# Visual Studio 13 doesn't build all changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2013, rebuild

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, C# settings.

For some reason, when I hit "build", it won't build all the changes I made. Only when I rebuild or clean and build, my changes are compiled correctly (of course).
Even when I just set a breakpoint and build, it says the breakpoint can't be hit.
I know I can just reset F6 to execute a rebuild, but because I have a big solution, this would always take about 10-15 seconds, even for the smallest changes..

I know this is a problem many people have faced, and there are some steps suggested to fix it. These don't work in my case though.

- Yes, I've set "On run, when projects are out of date" to "Always build" or "Prompt to build", both didn't work.
- Yes, I've checked the build configurations manager that all projects are checked to build.

I have a feeling that it's still something in my settings..
Because a few weeks ago I was still using Visual Studio 2012, and I had the same problem. Now in my company, I got VS13, and because of some specific settings they used my VS12 settings file to maintain them.
Only one other person in our IT-department has that problem, so the general company settings are not the problem. I can't recall changing anything on my own though..

So, did anybody find another way to solve this problem besides the 2 tips I listed above ?

Comment: Are you building a RT(mobile) app?

Comment: are you sure it's a build problem, or is it just the debugger that shows the wrong breakpoints?

Comment: It's not just breakpoints, it's any changes that I make. I've put in a messagebox on the start to test the problem while trying to fix it, and change the displayed text every time. It won't change my output.

Comment: And no, I'm building a DLL which is then copied to a start project. The copy is not the problem though, I've checked that.

Comment: @Dagon313 i only ever saw this with VS2013 when i had an RT project with a portable dll -> no changes to the dll were ever compiled unless i rebuilt dll first, then the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working in a team and you are not aloud to make these changes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561430.aspx

Comment: @HanBrouwer, how is the link related to the question?

Comment: TFS is used to setup a teamserver. Here is explained how you can do this. I don't know if there are other possiblities.

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages messing with project and environment settings without sucess. For me I fixed this problem by selecting configuration manager from the debug/release dropdown and ensuring that the build checkbox was ticked.[image]

After this it appears to build as and when needed.
HTH

Paul

Comment: Thanks but like I said in my post, I have already checked that and it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck: Options > Project And Solutions > Build And Run > "Only build startup project and dependencies on run"